# Conditional Data imputation in Python Using IF statement

Tags: python, if-statement, missing-data, imputation

I am trying to impute values in my dataset conditionally.

Say I have three columns, `If Column 1 is 1 then Column 2 is 0 and Column 3 is 0; If column 1 is 2 then Column 2 is Mean () and Column 3 is Mean()`.

I tried running an if statement with the function `any()` and defined the conditions separately.

However the conditions are not being fulfilled based on conditions, I am either getting all mean values or all zeroes.

I have posted this on Stackoverflow and haven’t gotten any response to help me with this. Please do suggest what should I apply to get this sorted.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Maybe include the code you've tried?  It's not exactly clear what you mean (the `mean()` of what?) but seeing the code might clarify your intent a bit.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If Column 1 = X then replace column 2 values as Mean, If Column 1 = Y then replace Column 2 values as 0. Facing Value error for writing the above code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61713051/if-column-1-x-then-replace-column-2-values-as-mean-if-column-1-y-then-repla)

Comment: I assume that other question is the one with the actual code; I'm flagging this one as a duplicate and moving your description into that question so it's all in one place.  :)